# How to manually delete a textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a growable Textfield widget that a user can add as many textfield as he wants.
I am using a list of textfields in this case. If user presses button to add textfield , it will be added to the list .

Also have created a function to delete the textfield if user wants and ima useing listName.removeAt()  method for this . But when i delete a textfield which got some value  there is a mismatch . I am deleting the textfield of that index but the value it holds shifts to another field.

Where i implement the code is :

```
Consumer(
                  builder: (ctx, ref, child) {
                    final customCourse =
                        ref.watch(customCourseTypeNotifierProvider);
                    return ListView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: customCourse.customCourses.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: MinimalInputField(
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                             
                            },
                            hintText: "",
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              onPressed: () {
                                
                                ref
                                    .read(customCourseTypeNotifierProvider)
                                    .removeCourse(index);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

In type_controller.dart

```
class CourseTypeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
    List<CustomCourseModel> customCourses = [];

  void addCourse() {
    customCourses.add(
      const CustomCourseModel(title: "", description: ""),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCourse(int index) {
    customCourses.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When `text` in `MinimalInputField` changes, the model is not updated and when the model is changed, `text` in `MinimalInputField` is not updated.

Using `TextField` could go something like this:

```
TextField(
  controller: TextEditingController()..text = customCourse.customCourses[index].title!,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    ref.read(customCourseTypeNotifierProvider).updateCourse(index, value);
  },
...
)

class CourseTypeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
...
  void updateCourse(int index, String title) {
    customCourses[index] = CustomCourseModel(title: title, description: "");
  }
...
}
```